# How to convert date and time from a line in a text file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I was wondering if there is a way to convert date and time from a pre-set value in a line from a text file.

For the date conversion, I need the day of the year. I found a way to get the current day of the year with this code:

```
from datetime import datetime
day_of_year = datetime.now().timetuple().tn_yday
print day_of_year
```

But will need it for past years also (ex; 1991, 1995, 2004).

For the time conversion, I  need the seconds of the day. The code I have that converts hours, minutes, and seconds to seconds of the day is:

```
def get_sec(s):
    x = s.split(':')
    return int(x[0]) * 3600 + int(x[1]) * 60 + int(x[2])
    print get_sec('17:36:00) //gives me an output of 63360
```

But I can't be inputting the values for hour, minutes, seconds each time since it has to read whatever value from the line in the text file.

The sample text file I have, lets call it datetime.txt, is:

```
1.a  Date Installed :    1991-01-19T00:00Z
     Date Removed   :    1993-02-08T00:00Z

1.b  Date Installed :    1993-02-09T00:00Z
     Date Removed   :    1994-01-12T00:00Z

1.c  Date Installed :    1994-01-12T00:00Z
     Date Removed   :    1994-02-16T17:36Z
```

To make sense of the sample text file, **for the time**, the 2 characters after the 'T' represents hours and the 2 characters after the colon ':' represents minutes. **For the date**, the 2 characters between the dash '-' represents months, and the 2 characters before the 'T' represents days. So for example 1.a, **time** 00 is hours, 00 is minutes. **date** 01 is months (January), 19 is days.

The current code I have now is:

```
with open('datetime.txt', 'r') as dt:
for line in dt:
    header = line.split(':')[0]
    if 'Date Installed' in header:
        year = line.split(':')[1].strip()[2:4]
        day_of_year = line.split(':')[1].strip()[5:7] + line.split(':')[1].strip()[8:10]
        sec_of_day = line.split(':')[1].strip()[14:16]
        print year,
        print day_of_year,
        print sec_of_day
```

The indexes I added is to tell which characters from the line in the text file to print, start to finish.

I've been stuck at this part of my script for a while now. Still new to Python so not quiet familiar with everything yet.

So how would I implement or add to my current code the two conversions for day and time? The purpose of this is so I can run a general code that will run and give me the same output, format and conversion, with other text files with different values.

Any help in the right direction is appreciated.

**Note**
I am not sure if this question is a duplicate to something else. I wasn't really quiet sure how to word my question properly, so I do apologize if it does end up being a duplicate. And also, this is not for school. Just for my own personal use at work to run different text files and extract/print specific parts of lines.

Comment: Why don't you use Python's standard library date and time support (called, inventively, [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html))?

Answer (score 1):

well once you've gotten the `1993-02-09T00:00Z` string, you can just do

```
import time, datetime
d = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.strptime('1993-02-09T00:00Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%MZ'))
```

which will give you a `datetime` object, which you can use accordingly

So then you can do things like `d.year`, `d.hour`, etc.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, `datetime.datetime.strptime('1993-02-09T00:00Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%MZ')` would work as well.

Comment: Ok that makes, thank you. But is there any way around not having to type the date in the code? Or is that out of the question and thats how i would have to do it by? Sorry if thats a silly question. Just looks tedious by having to type the dates every time.

Comment: downvote. Did you try to run it? `fromtimestamp()` expects a unix time (a float) but `time.strptime()` return `time.struct_time()` tuple. Also, `Z` implies UTC time while `fromtimestamp()` returns local time as a naive datetime object (potentially ambiguous value). `datetime.strptime()` (in this case) returns UTC time as a datetime object (it always exists  and it is unique).

Comment: @e.c.husk: obviously, you wouldn't type the date strings by hand. You read them from a file as it is said in your question.

Comment: @e.c.husk you'll always have to enter the date format (`%Y-%m-%dT%H:%MZ`), but if you're reading from a file then you shouldn't need to type the actual date.

Answer (score 0):

Your times are formatted according to the [iso 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) specification.

You can use [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) to parse iso8601 formatted datetimes.

```
data = """
1.a  Date Installed :    1991-01-19T00:00Z
     Date Removed   :    1993-02-08T00:00Z

1.b  Date Installed :    1993-02-09T00:00Z
     Date Removed   :    1994-01-12T00:00Z

1.c  Date Installed :    1994-01-12T00:00Z
     Date Removed   :    1994-02-16T17:36Z
"""

# Regular expression to find matches in the input data
import re

regex_pattern = re.compile(r"""
    (?P<key>\d+\.\w+).*?             # the key is <digits>.<letters>
    (?P<installed>[-:TZ0-9]{17}).*?  # the timestamps have length 17 
    (?P<removed>[-:TZ0-9]{17})
    """, 
    flags = re.VERBOSE | re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL
)
```

The regular expression is not very complicated. The verbose flag and named patterns is just to make it more readable. Here's a detailed explanation of the expression: https://regex101.com/r/oT0rG3/1

Once we have isolated the matches, parsing the iso timestrings is trivial:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

# Dictionary comprehension on the regex matches
items = {
    key: tuple(parse(ts) for ts in timestamps)
    for key, *timestamps in regex_pattern.findall(data)
}
```

Final output `items` is a dictionary:

```
{'1.a': (datetime.datetime(1991, 1, 19, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzutc()),
         datetime.datetime(1993, 2, 8, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzutc())),
 '1.b': (datetime.datetime(1993, 2, 9, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzutc()),
         datetime.datetime(1994, 1, 12, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzutc())),
 '1.c': (datetime.datetime(1994, 1, 12, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzutc()),
         datetime.datetime(1994, 2, 16, 17, 36, tzinfo=tzutc()))}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all dates are in the same format then it is easy to extract them from the file (not tested):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime

dates = {} # date -> label
with open('datetime.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        label, colon, date_string = line.partition(':')
        if colon:
            utc_time = datetime.strptime(date_string.strip(), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%MZ')
            dates[utc_time] = label.strip()
```